# TransformedDistribution with Conditioned

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Is the following attempt beyond Mathematica 11?

```
Z = TransformedDistribution[ (A + B)/2 \[Conditioned] A < B, {A \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[mA , sA], B \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[mB , sB]}]
```

When I try to get Mathematica to show me the PDF of Z, it doesn't work. I tried:

```
 PDF[Z, y]
```

Comment: Would that not work:                                                  Z = TransformedDistribution[ (A + B)/2 , {A \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[mA , sA], B \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[mB , sB]},Assumptions -> A < B ]  ?

Comment: @amator2357 The documentation says that the `Assumptions` are for parameters rather than the random variables.

Comment: OK, yeah, I thought that might have been the case, haven't read through the documentation properly, thanks for the heads up @JimB

Comment: @amator2357.  Join the club.

Comment: So, my code is fine but Mathematica 11 stumbles?

Comment: I don't think it stumbles.  I think it just won't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to derive an exact solution to this problem.

Given: $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables where $X \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and  $Y \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$, with parameter conditions:

[image]

**Problem**:  Find the pdf of $\frac{X+Y}{2} \; \big| \; X < Y$

1. Joint pdf of $(X,Y)$:

By independence, the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$, say $f(x,y)$ is simply the product of the individual pdf's:

[image]

2. Let $V = X - Y$. Then $V \sim N(\mu_1 - \mu_2, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)$ with cdf $\Phi(v)$.

Let constant $c = P(X<Y) = P(V<0) = \Phi(0)$ which is: (take care here with non-standard Mma notation)

[image]

3. Conditional joint pdf:

The conditional pdf $f\big((x,y) \; \big| \; X<Y\big) = \frac{f(x,y)}{P(X<Y)}$ is then `fcon`:

[image]

where all the dependence is captured within the `fcon` statement using the `Boole` statement, and we can enter the 'domain' as a rectangular structure on the real line, *i.e.*

```
domain[fcon] = domain[f]
```

4. Transformation $Z = \frac{X+Y}{2}$

Given the conditional joint pdf $f\big((x,y) \; \big| \; X<Y\big)$ ... let $Z = \frac{X+Y}{2}$ and $W = X$. Then the joint conditional pdf of $(Z,W)$, say $g(z,w)$, is obtained with:

[image]

where I am using the `Transform` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*, and the domain can again be entered as a rectangular set as:

[image]

Then, the marginal pdf of $Z = \frac{X+Y}{2}$ is:

[image]

... which is the exact solution. All done.

## Monte Carlo check

The following plot compares:

- the exact symbolic pdf derived above (red dashed curve)
- ... to the Monte Carlo simulated pdf (squiggly blue curve)

... here when: $\mu_1 = -1, \mu_2 = 4, \sigma_1 = 1, \sigma_2 = 12$

Looks fine.

[image]

Comment: @Wolfies, how do I place the two normal distributions and your solution on the same axis? I am trying to use Manipulate to examine your solution together with the normals. I will gladly open another question for this, if needed.

Comment: When I place your solution and the normals on different axis, the scale of the normals and your solution seem off. I suspect they may not be directly comparable. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, can mathStatica find the expectation of your solution? Mathematica cannot, it would appear.

Comment: You may have to resort to `NIntegrate` to find moments, given numerical parameter values.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer you desired but here is an approach to get the cdf and pdf using numerical integration.

Proportion of the time that `x1 < x2`  given than `x1` and `x2` are independent (this took 80 seconds):

```
int0 = Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], x1] PDF[NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2], x2], 
  {x2, -∞, ∞}, {x1, -∞, x2}, Assumptions -> {σ1 > 0, σ2 > 0}]

(* Integrate[(E^(-((x2 - μ2)^2/(2 σ2^2))) (1 + Erf[(x2 - μ1)/(Sqrt[2] σ1)]))/(2 Sqrt[2 π] σ2),
 {x2, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> {σ1 > 0, σ2 > 0}] *)
```

Proportion of the time that `(x1+x2)/2 < t` and `x1 < x2` given that `x1` and `x2` are independent (this took 100 minutes):

```
int1 = Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], x1] PDF[NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2], x2], 
  {x2, -∞, ∞}, {x1, -∞, Min[x2, 2 t - x2]}, Assumptions -> {σ1 > 0, σ2 > 0}]

(* Integrate[(E^(-((x2-μ2)^2/(2 σ2^2)))Erfc[(μ1 - Min[2 t - x2, x2])/(Sqrt[2] σ1)])/(2 Sqrt[2 π] σ2), 
  {x2, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> {σ1 > 0, σ2 > 0}] *)
```

So we can define a cdf using numerical integration:

```
cdf[t_, μ1_, μ2_, σ1_, σ2_] := NIntegrate[(
   E^(-((x2 - μ2)^2/(2 σ2^2))) Erfc[(μ1 - Min[2 t - x2, x2])/(Sqrt[2] σ1)])/(2 Sqrt[2 π] σ2),
   {x2, -∞, ∞}]/
  NIntegrate[(E^(-((x2 - μ2)^2/(2 σ2^2))) (1 + Erf[(x2 - μ1)/(Sqrt[2] σ1)]))/(2 Sqrt[2 π] σ2),
   {x2, -∞, ∞}]
```

For the pdf we can differentiate the part of the cdf that depends on `t` (this took 52 minutes):

```
FullSimplify[D[Integrate[(E^(-((x2 - μ2)^2/(2 σ2^2))) Erfc[(μ1 - Min[2 t - x2, x2])/(Sqrt[2] σ1)])/
  (2 Sqrt[2 π] σ2), {x2, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> {σ1 > 0, σ2 > 0}], t]]

(* (E^(-((-2 t + μ1 + μ2)^2/(2 (σ1^2 + σ2^2)))) Erfc[((t - μ2) σ1^2 + (-t + μ1) σ2^2)/
  (Sqrt[2] σ1 σ2 Sqrt[σ1^2 + σ2^2])])/(Sqrt[2 π] Sqrt[σ1^2 + σ2^2]) *)
```

We can now define a pdf function:

```
pdf[t_, μ1_, μ2_, σ1_, σ2_] := ((E^(-((-2 t + μ1 + μ2)^2/(2 (σ1^2 + σ2^2))))
    Erfc[((t - μ2) σ1^2 + (-t + μ1) σ2^2)/(Sqrt[2] σ1 σ2 Sqrt[σ1^2 + 2^2])])/
    Sqrt[2 π] Sqrt[σ1^2 + σ2^2]))/
  NIntegrate[(E^(-((x2 - μ2)^2/(2 σ2^2))) (1 + Erf[(x2 - μ1)/(Sqrt[2] σ1)]))/
  (2 Sqrt[2 π] σ2), {x2, -∞, ∞}]
```

Here's a test example:

```
(* Generate a random sample *)
n = 1000000;
SeedRandom[12345];
z = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, -1}, {1, 6}, 0], n];
z = Select[z, #[[1]] < #[[2]] &];
z = Total[#]/2 & /@ z;

(* Plot pdf's and cdf's *)
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[z];
Plot[{PDF[skd, t], pdf[t, 0, -1, 1, 6]}, {t, Min[z], Max[z]},
 PlotStyle -> {{LightGray, Thickness[0.03]}, {Red, Thickness[0.001]}},
 PlotLegends -> {"Simulations", "Numerical integration"}]

Plot[{CDF[skd, t], cdf[t, 0, -1, 1, 6]}, {t, Min[z], Max[z]},
 PlotStyle -> {{LightGray, Thickness[0.03]}, {Red, Thickness[0.001]}},
 PlotLegends -> {"Simulations", "Numerical integration"}]
```

[image: pdf and cdf]

Comment: How long did int1 take to compute on your system?

Comment: A long, long time.  I'll run it again later today and list the timing.  I also let some code run to compute the pdf.  I'll add that later today.